# Put a text banner in navigationbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I start to code an website, there I start to code in HTML with CSS. But, I think I made the mistake that I didn't put a `<div>` before I start to program.

Here is the code for the navbar:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 0px solid #bbb;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 19px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #112;
}
.active {
  background-color: #990000;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #990000;
}
ul.topnav li active {
  background-color: #990000;
}
ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  function myFunction() {
    var x=document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className==="topnav") {
      x.className +=" responsive";
    }
    else {
      x.className="topnav";
    }
  }
}
.videoWrapperOuter {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.videoWrapperInner {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}
.videoWrapperInner iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40.7em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="studio.html">Rent a Studio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to put a text banner on the right and when I collapse, so the text banner be in the middle in the navbar.

Comment: hi, did the answer below helped you in solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the below `li` to the list along with a `right` and `mob` class.

```
  <li class="right mob"><a href="#">Heading</a>
  </li>
```

Let me know if this is what you expected? Thanks!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 0px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 19px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #112;
}

.active {
  background-color: #990000;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.right{
  float: right;
  }

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #990000;
}

ul.topnav li active {
  background-color: #990000;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(.mob) {
    display: none;
  }

  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav li.right{
  float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.right{
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

.videoWrapperOuter {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.videoWrapperInner {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapperInner iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40.7em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="active mob">
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="studio.html">Rent a Studio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="right mob"><a href="#">Heading</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works, but now I want to put an text logo on the top, when you scrolling down, you can only see the navigation. when your scrolling up, the text banner comes up. Plus if it can be done, how to code an collapsing bottom, where you can put overview for the site, links to social media and such?

Comment: :) I think you should try that out first and post a new question if you get stuck somewhere, all the best!